# Redirect http requests to another server

Tags: networking, redirect

Is there any way to redirect HTTP requests on a certain ip address with a certain port (for example a random google IP address 173.194.112.151) to a http server that runs on my machine? (127.0.0.1:8080)

I tried using [Pound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pound)  but I don't know how to create such a rule and I don't really know if this is a solution.

Can somebody suggest a solution for this? Thank you

Comment: try squid proxy server  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html

Answer (score 0):

As part of the PC(system-1) which runs web service, you can use one additional PC(system-2) to get this thing done.

- From clients where you access the web service set the default gateway pointing to the system-2.
- set up port forwarding on system-2, for example 173.194.112.151:80 --> 192.168.1.10:808; where 192.168.1.10 is the system-1.

**TIP:** for this port forwarding scenario I recommended to use `firewalld` instead of `ufs` which comes as default firewall on Debian like system.

- you can install `firewalld` by `$ sudo apt-get install firewalld`
- make sure to disable `ufw` also.